# Server virtual processors and processing units

Tags: virtualization, partition, central-processing-unit

I am using PowerVM hypervisor with AIX operating system, and having troubles understanding the difference between virtual processors vs processing units.

Here is an example:
I have got a server with 6.00 Processors in total and 5.00 are available.

Afterwards I add a new server with the following specifications:
Minimum processing units 0.1
Desired processing units 0.1
Maximum processing units 1.0

Min virt processors: 1.0
Desired virt processors: 1.0
Maximum virt processors: 4.0

This is the part that confuses me:
The server will see 1 virtual processor running with 0.1 real proc running at the start. When reaching its maximum point will it be using 4 virt processors with each 0.25 real proc (1.0 / 4) or will it use 4 processors with 4.0 real proc ( 1 * 4 )

Thanks for reading and please leave a nice comment to help me understand this.

Comment: In the VM I have worked with, processing units and virtual processors do not work like that: Virtual processors are only what the guest partition sees, so it can do multi-threading and such (guest point of view). Processing units, on the other hand are how the host CPU is distributed between the guests. As it seems you are partitioning an IBM machine, max values will not be reached unless you perform some commands on the guest machine, but in that case, it will be using at most 1.0 real CPU (could be 1 real core * 100% usage or 4 real cores * 25% usage, it is indistinguishable)

Comment: @NuTTyX Thats exactly what I wanted to know! Thnx for reading the painfull explanation

Comment: @user3380195, take note that if you specify a certain processing capacity, there must be at least sufficient virtual cores to support it. That is: if you specify PU of 1.5, you would need at least 2 VC. It also applies for minimums: if you specify minimum 2 VC and the minimum asignable PU is 0.1, you would need to specify 0.2 to minimum PU as 0.1 would not divide into two processors (the hypervisor won't let you do such mistakes). You may read more in the [IBM redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247940.html?Open)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the desired state is 0.1 processing unit and 1 virtual processor, this is what you get, 1 virtual processor with 0.1 real processor.

Since the maximum state is 1.0 processing unit with 4 virtual processors, this is what you get. 4 virtual processors sharing 1 processing unit.

What don't you understand? You get what you ask for if the system has the resources to provide it.